# Using 1 Parameter per Table Matrix in Winform RDLC

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, parameters, rdlc

I am working on a report viewer for a small winform application. Is there a way for me to use 2-3 tables (Tablix) that each take a different parameter in the rdlc?

To clarify, I have this statement in my dataset

```
SELECT something
FROM Table
WHERE something_date = @date
```

and in my report, I would like to have 3 tables that display the dates 10/05/2016, 10/06/2016, and 10/07/2016

so that when I populate the rows and columns via load or button click I would use

```
this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSetScheduleReport.DataTable1, param1, param2, param3);
//where of course param1, param2, and param3 are the dates
```

so basically, the final output is

```
table for 10/05/2016
[something1]
[something2]
[something3]

table for 10/06/2016
[something1]
[something2]
[something3]

table for 10/07/2016
[something1]
[something2]
[something3]
```

Any other alternatives and suggestions would also be very helpful as I would still be learning tidbits from them.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two approaches to solve your problem.

First approach:- Create three different tables and pass on all the three tables to the RDLC; then for each tablix specify respective table as its datasource.

Second approach:- Create only one table which contains data of all the three dates and pass on this table to RDLC; additionally, pass on three different dates as report parameters. For all the tablix specify same table as datasource but apply fiter so that each tablix display data of specific date only.